# How to print the word "in"

Tags: pandas, string, jupyter-notebook, printing

I am currently working on a Intro to Pandas and Jupyter activity and I ran into an issue. I am trying to print the following string: ___ was published by ___ in ___.
The following code keeps on changing "in" to a iteration (correct me if that's the wrong terminology). How can I get it to print the word "in"?

```
print("row[0] + "was published by" + row[8] + "in" + row[9] + ".")
```

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 8)

Comment: `print(row[0] + "was published by" + row[8] + "in" + row[9] + ".")` You have an extra double quote at the beginning.

Comment: Assume the rest of the syntax is correct.

Comment: Or use f-string printing, `print(f"{row[0]} was published by {row[8]} in {row[9]}.")`

Comment: @ScottBoston THANK YOU SO MUCH! That removed the iteration "in" issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unbalanced double quotes:

Try:

```
print(row[0] + "was published by" + row[8] + "in" + row[9] + ".")
```

or use f-string:

```
print(f"{row[0]} was published by {row[8]} in {row[9]}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line is written in your code as it is written here in your post (if you just copied it directly) then it could be just the fact that you added a quote mark before row[0].
If that is the case then just changing :

`print("row[0] + "was published by" + row[8] + "in" + row[9] + ".")`

to :

`print(row[0] + " was published by " + row[8] + " in " + row[9] + " .")`

would do the trick!

or try :

`print(f"{row[0]} was published by {row[8]} in {row[9]} .")`

Hope that this helps!